# Find String and Add Extra at the end

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have the following string.

```
This is content 
[divider space="123" anything="123"]
more content
[divider space="123"]
some more text or shortcodes
```

the challenge is to first find string [divider ad then at the same time find ] once ] is found add [/divider] at the end. So the the final output will become:

```
This is content 
[divider space="123" anything="123"][/divider]
more content
[divider space="123"][/divider]
some more text or shortcodes
```

with the following code I can find the string.

```
str = 'This is content[divider space="123" anything="123"][/divider]more content[divider space="123"][/divider] some more text or shortcodes';
str = str.match(divider(.*)]");
```

how can I find first string and then the secondstring and add something [/divider] after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` function and pass a function inside

```js
$("p").html($("p").html().replace(/\[divider ([a-z]+\="\d+"\s?)+\]/g, s => s + "[/divider]" ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
This is content 
[divider space="123" anything="123"]
more content
[divider space="123"]
some more text or shortcodes
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. Looks like it will do the job, however can u please check my fiddle doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/5opg7dq4/

Comment: Hi @Richard Hamilton, I have found the problem, its with Regex, the first problem is if the variable name contains a capital letter for example if its anyThing="123" it doesn't work, secondly if any attribute is empty for example anything="" it again stop working, can you please change the regex, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5opg7dq4/4/